# How to set the theme for app objects in Mashups?

Tags: themes, qliksense, mashup

I am creating a mashup in Qlik Sense and want to use a different theme for the charts.

My Qlik Sense app(s) have a second theme that I want to use and thus have set in the app(s) to use the non-default one.
When I open the apps all is working fine, I get to see that non-default theme.

However in my Mashup website it does use the default Qlik Sense theme for the charts.

How can I tell it to use a different theme (via Javascript)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of the February 2018 release of Qlik Sense, you can call:
`qlik.theme.apply('my-theme');` after the `qlik.openApp(appId, config);`

It's even documented at:
https://help.qlik.com/en-US/sense-developer/February2018/Subsystems/APIs/Content/CapabilityAPIs/ThemeAPI/apply-method.htm

Answer (score 0):

Theming functionality is on the roadmap for upcoming version of Qlik Sense, but as of today not officially supported.

Update (as of 2018-02):
Themes are now supported in Qlik Sense Enterprise (release Feb 2018 +).

Comment: As of the February 2018 release, themes are supported by Qlik Sense. My mashup displays the default theme only.  What's the trick to apply a custom theme now?

Comment: Given that Qlik Sense supports it now, I have changed my accepted answer mark to the more current input from @Vbakke